# why I am getting 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I am getting this error in below snippet. I am calculating embedding from images.

```
----> 4     img = load_image(m.image_path())
      5     img = align_image(img)
      6     # scale RGB values to interval [0,1]

<ipython-input-14-23aefaa58a32> in load_image(path)
     12     # in BGR order. So we need to reverse them
     13     #destRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
---> 14     return img[...,::-1]
     15     #return destRGB
     16 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: yes.when I use this for face ditection its workingjc_orig = load_image(metadata[5].image_path())

Comment: before proceeding check whether `img` is empty or not @KaranPurohit

Comment: it's not empty.

Comment: for each class, I have 10 images but while importing them in for loop I found that it is also taking thumbs.db file. I think that's why I am getting the error. How to eliminate that?

Comment: Hard to say, since you don't show us how you get those paths. [mcve] please.

Comment: print(i,m.image_path()) is giving this:   0 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0001.jpg
1 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0002.jpg
2 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0003.jpg
3 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0004.jpg
4 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0005.jpg
5 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0006.jpg
6 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0007.jpg
7 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0008.jpg
8 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0009.jpg
9 images\Ariel_Sharon\Ariel_Sharon_0010.jpg
10 images\Ariel_Sharon\Thumbs.db

Comment: while passing images place a conditional checkpoint to only allow files ending with the image format `.jpg`. `if file.endswith('.jpg')`

Comment: finally, that worked. thanks for the support!

Comment: @KaranPurohit always place conditional checks when you have more than one file format within a directory!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but you have to ensure to use conditional checks when you have more than one file format in a directory.

In your case since you had a '.db' file along with your image files `.jpg`, python threw a subscriptable error.

As mentioned in the comments you can use a conditional checks prior to performing the desired operation by:

```
if file.endswith('.jpg'):
    #--- carry out your operation here
else:
    print(file)  #-- print the file not in the desired format
```